# When AngularJS caches HTTP requests does it cache the parsed JSON object or the string response itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, caching

I cache my HTTP requests using the built in AngularJS cache I.E.

```
.$http({
    url: "/api/data",
    method: "GET",
    cache: true
})
```

All the data returned from my API is gzipped JSON.  Some of the requests are quite large uncompressed (think megabytes) and a noticeable amount of browser time is spent converting from string to JSON.  I then wondered how AngularJS caches the HTTP response.  If it only caches the string response then everytime I access the cache it would have to convert to JSON again which could be expensive.

Can anyone shed some light on what exactly AngularJS caches so I can decide how best to proceed i.e. for certain big calls cache the data as an object in a service rather than using the HTTP cache.

Comment: should cache response object, you always can run js in debug to see detaisl

Comment: It stores as strings. Angular performs toJSON and fromJSON on it. This creates memory spikes hence I can't use it.

Comment: @bhantol Thanks, got any links or references I can look at?

Comment: @Chris https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching says it `When caching is enabled, $http stores the response from the server using the relevant cache object. The next time the same request is made, the response is returned from the cache without sending a request to the server.` Here the meaning of response is not just the data but also the headers etc as if a real response was received. The second cell of the response array is data or error. Checkout `sendReq` in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.2/src/ng/http.js

Comment: toJSON and fromJSON occurs in the default `transformResponse` function inside $http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the cache yourself:

```
var p = $http({
     url: url,
     method: "GET",
     cache: true
})

p.then(function(response) {
     vm.data = response.data;
     vm.info = $cacheFactory.info();
     console.log($cacheFactory.get('$http'));
     console.log($cacheFactory.get('$http').get(url));
     vm.value = $cacheFactory.get('$http').get(url)[1];
     vm.typeOf = typeof vm.value;
})
```

The '$http' cache stores each item as an array with 4 items:

- [0] response.status
- [1] response.data
- [2] response.headers()
- [3] response.statusText

The JSON data is stored as the raw string before it is parsed and transformed by any response interceptors.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0b1zyx6s/)